# Unable to Connect to Local ASP.NET Web API from MAUI App on Android Tablet

Tags: c#, asp.net, localhost, maui

I have an ASP.NET Web API running on my local machine and I’m trying to access it from a MAUI app running on an Android tablet. The API works fine when I access it from my PC using http://localhost:5169/api, but it doesn’t work when I try to access it from the tablet using http://192.168.xx.xxx:5169/api.

- Allowed port 5169 for inbound rule in Firewall of the PC.
- Added CORS in the Program.cs file to allow calls.
- Added a network security configuration in AndroidManifest.xml to allow clear-text traffic. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check)

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

When I debug, my API call in MAUI just throws an exception without any response code, and there are no logs in the API .NET app. The URI works in Postman, but not on my tablet.

I’m still in the development stage and I don’t want to deploy my app yet, so I need a solution that works for local development.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what else I could try? Could this be an issue with my network security configuration or something else?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  Timeout?  Exception?

Comment: When I debug, it just throws an exception without any response code, and there are no logs in the API .NET app. The URI works in Postman, but not on my tablet.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: [0:] Exception Getting Orders : System.Net.WebException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.xx.xxx not permitted
 ---> Java.IO.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.xx.xxx not permitted
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 11884
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod(String

Comment: That seems like a pretty clear error message.  Your network config is not setup for cleartext to 192.168.x.x

Comment: I fixed that, Now I got his Exception 
System.Net.WebException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: I fixed that by using this
public static HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                    return true;
                return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
            return handler;
        }
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: There are numerous existing questions about that error message